# How to select an element by class inside LI with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I know similar to this was asked allready, but my exampe is quite different, and can't manage to make it work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xhUZd/

```
<ul id="list">
<li>
    <div class="box1">
       <span class="one"></span>
       <span class="two"></span>
       <span class="three"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
       <span class="one"></span>
       <span class="two"></span>
       <span class="three"></span>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="box1">
       <span class="one"></span>
       <span class="two"></span>
       <span class="three"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
       <span class="one"></span>
       <span class="two"></span>
       <span class="three"></span>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Mission:**

When HOVER

span.one from "Box2" - ADD CLASS "bg1" to span.one from "Box1"

span.two from "Box2" - ADD CLASS "bg2" to span.two from "Box1"

span.three from "Box2" - ADD CLASS "bg3" to span.three from "Box1"

**This must work in EACH "li" individually.**

Please help!

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the details explained at the bottom of your post. You want to trigger the class on the same cell from the *previous* row, right?

Comment: Well, not really. I tested you example, from your Answer. My problem MAIN problem is to make this work FOR EACH <LI> SEPARATELY.

Comment: And second this need to work only when mouse is over SPAN from container BOX2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.box2 span', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        box1 = self.closest('li').find('.box1'),
        i = self.index();
    box1.find('span').eq(i).addClass('bg' + (i + 1));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xhUZd/1/).

If you'd like to have a second click (or alternate clicks) toggle the class-name, replace `addClass()` with `toggleClass()`:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.box2 span', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        box1 = self.closest('li').find('.box1'),
        i = self.index();
    box1.find('span').eq(i).toggleClass('bg' + (i + 1));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xhUZd/1/).

Somehow I'd managed to miss the requirement for classes to be manipulated on hovering the elements, rather than clicking; so with that acknowledged the actual working answer would be as follows:

```
$('#list').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.box2 span', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        box1 = self.closest('li').find('.box1'),
        i = self.index();
    box1.find('span').eq(i).toggleClass('bg' + (i + 1));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhUZd/3/), as adapted/corrected by the OP himself.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: This SOLVED, but i made some modification, little one. you can see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhUZd/3/

Comment: Nicely done! (Sorry, somehow I didn't see the 'hover' requirement on my reading of the question).

Comment: +1, u beat me to it, but your answer was better. didn't think of doing 'i = self.index()'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I missed requirements entirely. Here's a new attempt that assumes you want the hover behaviour to follow all SPANs across all DIVs across all LIs - hovering over span.two in .box3 would add class bg2 to span.two in .box2.

```
$(function () {
    var classMap = {
        one: 'bg1',
        two: 'bg2',
        three: 'bg3'
    };

    $('#list').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li div span', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .closest('div')
            .prev('div')
            .find('span.' + $this.attr('class'))
            .toggleClass(classMap[$this.attr('class')]);
    });
});
```